# Should I show a row icon on hover?

Tags: icons, hover

I have several rows of content, with small font icons to the right of each row for actions to take.

---

[image: UI Sample]

---

I feel these icons clutter up the look of the page, so I am considering a default opacity of 0 on the icons, and then on `:hover` of the row, to raise the opacity with a rapid CSS transition.

However, I haven't seen this much in the wild, and I'm wondering if it is considered bad UX.

Are there any rules on this?

Comment: DPo1: We do basically that and our users seem to like it.

Comment: Okay thanks. What does DPo1 refer to?

Comment: "Data Point of One" (why I made it a comment and not an answer.)

Comment: Okay, understood!

Comment: The Netflix DVD queue does it too, hiding Move and Remove.

Answer (score 3):

It is fine to do so usually, because:

- the repeating controls for the rows may, indeed, create clutter,
- an action you can perform on a row only makes sense in this particular row context,
- as the same controls will be hidden for the other rows, User will only see the exact controls they need to operate the currently hovered row.

However, you must remember that:

- hover actions will not work on mobile (in case you need it),
- anything that conveys some information that can be different in case of some rows should not be hidden. I can see you have one such thing, which is "Active" switch. It **both informs and allows control** the data behind it,
- it is definitely good to bridge all the elements in the row with a highlight on hover, so that the connection between row name and controls is provided (just imagine dots are highlight):

  ```
  Foo     Bar                                      [active switch]
  Fig.....Jam............[edit icon].[delete icon].[active switch]
  Fizz    Buzz                                     [active switch]
  ```